# Trouble to put two line charts in the same ggplot plot

Tags: r, plot, charts, ggplot2

Hi I would like to plot two line chart in one chart. Here is how my data looks like

```
query,trace,precision,recall
safe.order.q3.txt,sstr_cpu_50000_100m,49.774,24.8442
safe.order.q3.txt,sstr_oper_50000_100m,49.8735,24.885
safe.sem.q1.txt,ran_50000_100m,74.9204,24.8125
safe.sem.q1.txt,sys_50000_100m,58.1995,11.8975
safe.sem.q1.txt,rstr_cpu_50000_100m,75.6115,25.1855
safe.sem.q1.txt,rstr_oper_50000_100m,75.2262,24.9382
safe.sem.q1.txt,sstr_cpu_50000_100m,74.997,25.0963
safe.sem.q1.txt,sstr_oper_50000_100m,75.4195,25.3233
safe.sem.q2.txt,ran_50000_100m,78.6449,24.6323
safe.sem.q2.txt,sys_50000_100m,10.9353,0.255188
safe.sem.q2.txt,rstr_cpu_50000_100m,79.3762,24.6961
safe.sem.q2.txt,rstr_oper_50000_100m,79.1872,24.8607
```

And here is the ggplot code which is stored in `recprec.r`

```
w <- read.csv(file="../queryResults/comparison.100m.dat", head=TRUE, sep=",")
sem1 <- subset(w, query=="safe.sem.q1.txt")
p1 <- ggplot(data=sem1, aes(group=1, x=trace, y=precision, color=trace)) + layer(geom="line") + geom_text(aes(y=precision + .4, label=precision))
p2 <- ggplot(data=sem1, aes(group=1, x=trace, y=recall, color=trace)) + layer(geom="line") + geom_text(aes(y=recall + .4, label=recall))
grid.arrange(p1, p2)
print(p1, p2)
```

The execution of the code produces the following warning and the char depicted in the image below where each line chart appears in a separated char

```
> source("recprec.r")
Erreur dans if (newpage) grid.newpage() : 
  l'argument n'est pas interprétable comme une valeur logique
De plus : Message d'avis :
In if (newpage) grid.newpage() :
  la condition a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé
```

[image]

What do I have to change in order to have both line charts in the same plot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them both in the same plot, then you want to add layers to a plot -- not arrange multiple plots. Try

```
ggplot(data=sem1, aes(group=1, x=trace)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=precision)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=recall)) + 
  geom_text(aes(y=precision + .4, label=precision)) + 
  geom_text(aes(y=recall + .4, label=recall))
```

Comment: the final code `p <- ggplot(...) print(p)` doesn't work and here is the error. `Erreur dans eval(expr, envir, enclos) : colonnes non définies sélectionnées`

Comment: I've made an update. I used the proper `geom_line` rather than the generic `layer()` which you were originally using.

Comment: It just work fine now ! thanks a lot. It appear that bar chart would be more fancier than line ones. how can I go from line to bar charts in your code ?

Comment: Try changing geom_line to geom_bar. Also, you night want to find a ggplot tutorial. This is pretty basic stuff. In the future, you should not ask new questions in the comments that are sufficiently different than the original post. If you have a new question, start a new thread.